# Using 2D wave equation to find conservation of energy

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

[image]

I am not sure what to do here. How am I supposed to define it? By solving the 2D wave equation and then using energy equation to find that expression ? Also, how am I supposed to show the last part? Can someone help me on this? Appreciate your help and support.

Comment: Integrate by parts

Comment: which one? $E(u)$ equation?? I know that I have to take derivative of $E(u)$ with respect to $t$ and show that its 0. But before that I dont know wht n how to do it. Can someone help me more on this?